# How to map a preprocessing function to a tf.data Dataset after batching rather than before?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tf.data.dataset

**Short version:**

How do I apply a function to a `tf.data` Dataset *after* batching, like so:

```
ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
ds = ds.map(process_batch)
...
```

**Details:**

I'm trying to learn to use the `tf.data` API by playing with a simple image classification project. I'm looking at ways to make the pipeline more efficient and I'm following [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data_performance#vectorizing_mapping) guide (***Vectorized Mapping***).

The idea being to have the preprocessing function that reads/scales/normalizes images and extracts labels come *after* the batching. Here is my setup:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
import glob

data_path = "data/img_data"
img_height = 64
img_width = 64
AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE
batch_size=32

img_files = glob.glob(f"{data_path}/*/*.jpg")
n_imgs = len(img_files)

ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(img_files,shuffle=False)
ds = ds.shuffle(n_imgs,reshuffle_each_iteration=False)

class_names = [i.split("/")[-1] for i in glob.glob(f"{data_path}/*")]
```

Images are stored in named folders on disk. Everything is fine if I apply the parse function (`process_img` below) to individual image files, like so:

```
def process_img(filepath):
    label = tf.strings.split(filepath,"/")[-2]
    label = tf.argmax(label==class_names)
    img = filepath
    img = tf.io.read_file(filepath)
    img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
    img = tf.image.resize(img,[img_height,img_width])
    img = tf.cast(img,tf.float32)/255
    return img,label

def config_ds(ds):
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=ds.cardinality().numpy())
    ds = ds.map(process_img,num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    return ds

ds1 = config_ds(ds)
```

But I can't get the same idea to work over a pre-batched dataset, like so:

```
@tf.function
def process_batch(batch):
    batch_labels = []
    batch_imgs = []
    for i in batch:
        
        label = tf.strings.split(i,os.sep)[-2]
        label = tf.argmax(label==class_names)
        batch_labels.append(label)
        
        img = tf.io.read_file(i)
        img = tf.io.decode_jpeg(img, channels=3)
        img = tf.image.resize(img,[img_height,img_width])
        img = tf.cast(img,tf.float32)/255
        batch_imgs.append(img)        
    
    batch_labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(batch_labels, dtype=tf.int64)
    batch_imgs = tf.convert_to_tensor(batch_imgs, dtype=tf.float32)
    return imgs,labels

def config_ds2(ds):
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=ds.cardinality().numpy())
    ds = ds.batch(batch_size,drop_remainder=True)
    ds = ds.map(process_batch)
    return ds

ds2 = config_ds2(ds)
```

I've tweaked the code many times, and I feel like this is the closest I've got (I say that, because if I run the same code as contained in `process_batch` in a for loop over `ds.shuffle(...).batch(...)` it prints out more or less what I'm looking for - although I realise that's not much to go on).

The error I get from the above is:

```
InaccessibleTensorError: in user code:

    File "/var/folders/2c/cr8tgk091dg1qcqlnkxypj5m0000gn/T/ipykernel_17058/3752611221.py", 
line 54, in process_batch  *
        batch_labels = tf.convert_to_tensor(batch_labels, dtype=tf.int64)

    InaccessibleTensorError: <tf.Tensor 'while/ArgMax:0' shape=() dtype=int64> is out of scope and 
cannot be used here. Use return values, explicit Python locals or TensorFlow collections to access it.
    Please see 
https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#all_outputs_of_a_tffunction_must_be_return_values 
for more information.

The tensor <tf.Tensor 'while/ArgMax:0' shape=() dtype=int64> cannot be accessed from 
FuncGraph(name=process_batch, id=4966476864), because it was defined in 
FuncGraph(name=while_body_135, id=4967155888), which is out of scope.
```

I followed the link in the error which takes me [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/function#all_outputs_of_a_tffunction_must_be_return_values), but I couldn't get much out of it. I'm also confused because the error references a `while` loop that doesn't appear in the code...

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're using python code inside the `preprocess_batch` function. Because any function passed to the `.map` op is traced the function you pass is always ran in graph mode (as per the [tf.data.map doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map).
As defined in the doc, you have 3 options:

1. Rely on AutoGraph to convert Python code into equivalent graph code.
2. Use [tf.py_function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_function) wrapper and pass the `preprocess_batch` to it and incur a performance penalty.
3. Use [tf.numpy_function](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/numpy_function) that behaves the sames as `tf.py_function` but receives and must return only numpy arrays.

So, as you stated, for the single item the code works. This works because TF AutoGraph is able to convert the code, the function doesn't contain any side effects or python conditionals/loops.

For the batched version however you have the side-effect of dynamically constructing a list:

```py
batch_imgs = []
for i in batch:
    ...
    batch_imgs.append(image)
```

so AutoGraph isn't able to properly convert this code to its graph representation.

You then try to have TensorFlow do the conversion to TF ops for you by annotating the function with `@tf.function` but `@tf.function` won't handle side-effects such as appending to a list or printing elements and that behavior is described in the [py.function documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/function):

> Important: Any Python side-effects (appending to a list, printing with print, etc) will only happen once, when func is traced. To have side-effects executed into your tf.function they need to be written as TF ops

For your code it'd be something like:

```py
@tf.function
def process_batch(batch):
  batch_imgs = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.float32, size=0, dynamic_size=True)
  batch_labels = tf.TensorArray(dtype=tf.int64, size=0, dynamic_size=True)

  for i in range(len(batch)):
    filename = batch[i]
    img = tf.io.read_file(filename)
    ...
    batch_imgs = batch_imgs.write(i, image)

  return batch_imgs.stack(), batch_labels.stack()
```